How to push prism db React
I'm working on a project where a build Reddit clone using react and I'm trying to connect my database but keep getting an error saying: Invalid params: invalid type: map, expected a string.
I'm assuming it has something to do with my prism.schema (below) however, I'm new to react and prisma and I'm not sure how to get by this error
atasource db {
  provider          = "postgresql"
  url               = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?

  username String? @unique

  image    String?
  accounts Account[]
  sessions Session[]
}

After I run npc prism generate and prism db push it returns this error:
Invalid params: invalid type: map, expected a string.
Using neondb for the database, however, not sure if that's relevant to the problem as I had the same issue using supabase

What is npc? Exactly which command produces the error? Also, React being a front-end technology likely has nothing to do with this question

Searching for the error message turned up this issue immediately ~ https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/24644. What research did you do before posting this question?

@Phil searched a couple of different forums but this is the first I've seen that specific solution, thank you.
